About the uniqueness of the Jordan normal form of nilpotent matrices. ("Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.)
I am reading "Linear Algebra" by Ichiro Satake.
The following picture is about the normal form of nilpotent matrices.
In the picture, the author wrote as follows:

If there is another normal form similar to $N$, the number of $i\times i$ matrices of the form $(\S\S)$ appearing in that canonical form is clearly equal to $$r_i-r_{i+1}=2m_i-m_{i-1}-m_{i+1}=\operatorname{rank}N^{i-1}+\operatorname{rank}N^{i+1}-2\operatorname{rank}N^{i}.$$
Therefore, this number is uniquely determined by $N$, and hence the normal form of
$N$ is essentially unique.

I can understand why $r_i-r_{i+1}$ is uniquely determined by $N$:
$m_1,\dots,m_\nu$ are obviously uniquely determined by $N$.
So, each $r_i:=m_i-m_{i-1}$ is also uniquely determined by $N$.
So, each $r_i-r_{i+1}$ is also uniquely determined by $N$.
(I don't know why the author wrote the equation $r_i-r_{i+1}=2m_i-m_{i-1}-m_{i+1}=\operatorname{rank}N^{i-1}+\operatorname{rank}N^{i+1}-2\operatorname{rank}N^{i}$.)
But why does this imply the normal form of $N$ is essentially unieque?
I cannot understand about this.
The author's proof provides one method for calculating a normal form of a nilpotent matrix $N$. It can be understood that, if a normal form of $N$ is computed using this method, essentially the same normal form will be obtained. However, doesn't this reasoning leave unclear whether, if there were an entirely different method for calculating a normal form of $N$ and that method was used, essentially the same normal form would also be obtained?
Is the author's proof really perfect?


Knowing the number of blocks which are of given dimension, for every possible dimension, is sufficient to find the normal form since you can just concatenate blocks diagonally and you get the result (the uniqueness is up to ordering of blocks).
However, I'm not sure whether ri−ri+1 is actually the number of i by i blocks or its the number of k by k blocks for each k bigger than or equal i. I still think that this is enough to find the number of blocks for each dimension.
